# Understanding 'parse_str' in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, query-string

I'm a PHP newbie trying to find a way to use *[parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)* to parse a number of URLs from a database (note: not from the request, they are already stored in a database, don't ask... so _GET won't work)

So I'm trying this:

```
    $parts = parse_url('http://www.jobrapido.se/?w=teknikinformat%C3%B6r&l=malm%C3%B6&r=auto');
    parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
    return $query['w'];
```

Please note that here I am just supplying an example URL, in the real application the URL will be passed in as a parameter from the database. And if I do this it works fine. However, I don't understand how to use this function properly, and how to avoid errors.

First of all, here I used "w" as the index to return, because I could clearly see it was in the query. But how do these things work? Is there a set of specific values I can use to get the entire query string? I mean, if I look further, I can see "l" and "r" here as well...

Sure I could extract those too and concatenate the result, but will these value names be arbitrary, or is there a way to know exactly which ones to extract? Of course there's the "q" value, which I originally thought would be the only one I would need, but apparently not. It's not even in the example URL, although I know it's in lots of others.

So how do I do this? Here's what I want:

1. Extract all parts of the query string that gives me a readable output of the search string part of the URL (so in the above it would be "teknikinformatör Malmö auto". Note that I would need to translate the URL encoding to Swedish characters, any easy way to do that in PHP?)
2. Handle errors so that if the above doesn't work for some reason, the method should only return an empty string, thus not breaking the code. Because at this point, if I were to use the above with an actual parameter, *$url*, passed in instead of the example URL, I would get errors, because many of the URLs do not have the "w" parameter, some may be empty fields in the database, some may be malformed, etc. So how can I handle such errors stably, and just return a value if the parsing works, and return empty string otherwise?

There seems to be a very strange problem that occurs that I cannot see during debugging. I put this test code in just to see what is going on:

```
function getQuery($url)
{
    try
    {
        $parts = parse_url($url);
        parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
        if (isset($query['q'])) {
            /* return $query['q']; */
            return '';
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Now, obviously in the real code I would want something like the commented out part to be returned. However, the puzzling thing is this:

With this code, as far as I see, every path should lead to returning an empty string. But this does not work - it gives me a completely empty grid in the result page. No errors or anything during debugging, and objects look fine when I step through them during debugging.

However, if I remove everything from this method except return ''; then it works fine - of course the field in the grid where the query is supposed to be is empty, but all the other fields have all the information as they should. So this was just a test. But how is it possible that code that should only be able to return an empty string does not work, while the one that only returns an empty string and does nothing else does work? I'm thoroughly confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the problem was with Swedish characters - if I used *[utf8_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)* on the value before returning it, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the query parameters is entirely up to the application that handles the URL, so there is no "right" parameter - it might be `w`, `q`, or `searchquery`. You can heuristically search for the most common variables (=guess), or return an array of all arguments. It depends on what you're trying to achieve.

`parse_str` already decodes urlencoding. Note that urlencoding is a way to encode *bytes*, not characters. It depends on what encoding the application expects. Usually (and in this example query), that should be UTF-8 everywhere, so you should be covered on 1.

Test whether the value exists, and if not, return the empty string, like this:

```
$heuristicFields = array('q', 'w', 'searchquery');
foreach ($heuristicFields as $hf) {
  if (isset($query[$hf])) return $query[$hf];
}
return '';
```

The function returns `null` if the input is valid, and runs into errors (i.e., displays warning messages) when the URL is obviously invalid. The *try*...*catch* block has no effect.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that explanation, and I will try your example. However, I don't feel good about "guessing" what the parameters might be... So what about your other suggestion, that I can return an array of all arguments? I tried a test of that, by returning the first in the array: $query[0], but that threw an error, probably because of the malformed urls and empty fields and all that, I guess...So if I do parse_str and it fails, how can I check for that, and then just concatenate the array you mentioned instead of guessing what the parameters might be?

Comment: @AndersSvensson As I wrote, it depends on what you want to do in the first place. Do you want to find the search query? Or something else. Oh, and while you can make an educated guess about a parameter name, you should **not** make one about the reason for an error, and disregard an alternative simply because your code is erroneous. The correct way to get the first element in the query array is `reset($query);`, since its indices are not numerical. `parse_str` never fails, it just might return an empty array. You can check `count($query) == 0` and then return 0.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but might parse_url fail? Because as soon as I pass in the real urls (including malformed ones and empty strings) the whole function fails, I get an empty grid in the result page. If it was just that this function had returned an empty string I would have just gotten that field empty, not the entire grid... So how can I check that parse_url doesn't fail before passing it to parse_str?

Comment: @AndersSvensson `parse_url` can fail and then returns false (check the result like this: `if ($parts === false) return '';`. However, this only happens if the URL is quite obviously invalid (like, an empty string). More likely, there is a bug in your implementation. Feel free to ask another question with the **whole code** and at least one **failing test case**, and notify me here.

Comment: It might be really difficult to post all of the code, that would involve a lot. But I'll try editing the question with what seems to be the problem...

Comment: @AndersSvensson Well, the test case is enough, although the input (you can get it with `var_export($url)`) would be a nice addition. Unfortunately, php is not Python, and the edited code does not what you expect. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it turned out it had to do with Swedish characters and other special characters in the data, so basically the original code worked fine as long as I used utf8_encode() on the result... I'll upvote you for your helpful advice at least :-)